# LaTeX lstlisting not highlighting keywords when basic style is ttfamily

Tags: latex, formatting, code-formatting

I'm working on a LaTeX document and using lstlisting to display my Java source code. My setup looks like this:

```
\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\bfseries,
  language=Java,
  frame=single,
  aboveskip=11pt,
  belowskip=11pt,
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false
}
```

The keywords are not highlighted bold when using ttfamily, but if I use small or don't specify the basic style, they're highlighted fine.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default font in LaTeX, Computer Modern, does not provide a bold version of the teletype family. You can install this as the `bold-extra` package; see [this FAQ entry](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=bold-extras) for details.

Comment: @Lex: If this answer fixes your problem, you need to hit the check mark by it to "accept" the answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq for how to ask a good question. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Right, I think I oversaw it yesterday, but thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to swap which fonts you're using for bold as described here: http://www.macfreek.nl/mindmaster/LaTeX_Bold_Typewriter_Font

Just putting this line at the top of my document worked for me on a pretty standard Ubuntu build:

```
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{bx}{n}{<5><6><7><8><9><10><10.95><12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmttb10}{}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an alternative approach (a bit simplee IMHO) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33039/using-ttfamily-with-bfseries-or-how-to-enable-bold-in-fixed-width-font) using a Courier font instead of the default Computer Modern:

```
% Using Courier font
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle=\ttfamily\bfseries]
y:=2
\end{lstlisting}
```

All credits goes of cause to Marco Daniel!